# Cant figure out how to display table data with only same values

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am using nodejs, with express, mysql and js. I have a table called `EVENT` and one query im working on is to display only the data on the table that has the same `start_time`. Basically displaying all the data with *conflicting* start_time.

I tried a bunch of different queries but I cant manage to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
db.query(
    'select start_time 
    FROM EVENT 
    INNER JOIN select start_time FROM EVENT GROUP BY start_time HAVING COUNT(EVENT > 1)', 
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({error: true, message: "Error Querying Database"});
        // throw err;
      }
```

Comment: Would you please show us sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking to pull out all records where `start_time` is not unique. Here are a few solutions, ordered by descending efficiency.

In MySQL 8.0, this can be achived with window functions, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT e.*, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY start_time) cnt FROM events
) x WHERE cnt > 1
```

In earlier versions, you can use an `EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM events e
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM events e1 
    WHERE e1.start_time = e.start_time AND e1.id != e.id
)
```

This assumes that you have a column that can be used to disambiguate the records having the same `start_time` (I called it `id`). If you don't, you can use an `IN` condition with a correlated subquery that lists the `start_time`s that occur more than once, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE event_date IN (
    SELECT start_time FROM events GROUP BY start_time HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: or a join to an inline view `SELECT e.* FROM ( SELECT c.start_time FROM event c GROUP BY c.start_time HAVING SUM(1) > 1 ) d JOIN event e ON e.start_time <=> d.start_time`  +10

Comment: In this case the question is a really obvious duplicate, which you should have voted to close as such, not answer it again.

Comment: @Shadow: ok, agreed...

Comment: @spencer7593: yes good one... I would personnaly favor the inline view it over the `IN` approach, and make it my third pick in the list!